# Optimization in Bayesian Settings

Tags: bayesian, optimization

I am curious to know of instances when optimization is used in Bayesian settings (not to be confused with Bayesian optimization). The obvious contenders are

- MAP estimation
- Optimization as part of variational Bayes for making inference for Bayesian models.
- Finding posterior mode(s) for implementing MCMC (similar in flavor to MAP estimation)

This seems like not an exhaustive list, and I feel I may be missing some interesting problems. My motivation is to identify areas in Bayesian analysis where an expert in optimization might be able to contribute research in.

Comment: Would you include decision theory, as posterior loss minimisation?

Comment: @Xi'an technically yes, but there are closed form optimizers under the usual losses, so that makes it uninteresting. However, for non-usual losses, there may be more to it.

Comment: Actually for most losses the solutions are not closed-form. Take for instance the functional distances I called [intrinsic losses](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00133173.pdf). Or even $L^p$ losses for $p\not\in\{1,2\}$.

Comment: @Xi'an Most definitely yes, in that case. (I was thinking more squared error, absolute deviation etc).